# Vb.Net - Get File Count from Directory based on Date

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone please help -

How to check if we have received (let's say file name "Test.csv") for today in a directory which hold "Test.csv" for each day of month.

So I want to check if we have received "Test.csv" for today (means 23-Jul-13)

I'm struggling to get directory contents based on date.

Regards

Comment: See if the file exists, then check its creation date or last modified date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and Linq:

```
Dim csvFiles = From csv In Directory.EnumerateFiles("DirectoryPath", "*Test.csv", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
               Where File.GetCreationTime(csv).Date = Date.Today
For Each csvPath In csvFiles
    Console.WriteLine(csvPath)
Next
```

If you are on .NET 2 as commented, you don't have Linq and `Directory.EnumerateFiles`, then use `GetFiles` and loops:

```
Dim csvFilesToday = New List(Of String)
For Each csv In Directory.GetFiles("DirectoryPath", "*Test.csv", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    If File.GetCreationTime(csv).Date = Date.Today Then
        csvFilesToday.Add(csv)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Im getting message directory.enumeratefiles is not member of system.io.directory. Please advise

Comment: @ConradJagger: Then you are not using at least .NET framework 4.0, what version are you using? You can replace it with `Directory.GetFiles` which loads all file-names into memory before it starts processing.

Comment: after changing to getfiles it says "expression of type '1-dimensional array of string' is not querable. make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or namespace import for linq provider"

Answer (score 0):

Hey Try This to get Current date file in specific folder

```
Imports System.IO



Dim directory = New DirectoryInfo("D:\TestPic")
    Dim myFile2 = directory.GetFiles().Where(Function(a) a.LastWriteTime.[Date] =                            DateTime.Today).ToList()

    For Each csvPath In myFile2
        Console.WriteLine(csvPath)
    Next
```

hope it helps you